# Tight coupling of photons and baryons before recombination

Tags: cosmology, perturbation-theory, cosmic-microwave-background, multipole-expansion

I am trying to understand the equations of CMB anisotropies. In the book I am studying with, the author wants to show that, when solving for the photon perturbations in the tightly coupled limit (before recombination), the higher order moments of the perturbed Boltzmann equation for photons can be neglected:

[image]

The reasoning seems circular to me: It is shown that the $\Theta_l$ are strongly decreasing with $l$ by assuming that they are strongly decreasing with $l$. Instead of neglecting $\Theta_{l+1}$ in 8.10 one could also neglect $\Theta_{l-1}$ and show that the moments are increasing...

It would be very nice if someone could clarify this "proof" for me.